# Ancillary statistics and the use of Basu theorem

Tags: statistics, order-statistics

Let Y1, Y2, ....., Yn be the order statistics of a random sample of size n from the distribution exp(theta) 
If R= ( n Y1 / M) where M = summation Yi . To show that R and M are independent ??

Applying Basu's theorem i've verified that M is complete sufficient statistics , i still have to show that R is ancillary. 
Will anybody help me in finding the distribution of R ?